# Regular expression to limit character & number

Tags: javascript, numbers, expression, character

my regular expression requirement is number and character combined exp. and this limited 5~15 characters.

for example,

```
abcd1, abc1d, a21ab, 1abcd, abcvda123 ...
ABCd1, Abc1d,
```

not allowed exampled,

```
abcd!1, !adf2a, abcd!a, abcd!2 ...
abc1, ab1c, 1abc, !abc ...
```

my regex exp is

```
^(?=.+[a-zA-Z])(?=.+[0-9]).{5,15}$
```

but is too bad.

Comment: All your examples contain one number (considering `21` as one number). Is `"a1c2e"` valid? What about `"abcde"` or `"12345"`?

Comment: test value must contain one number and one character. for example, abcd1, 1abcd.

Answer (score 1):

Change `.{5,15}` to `[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,15}`.

Also, in the lookaheads, change `.+` to `.*`. Otherwise, it won't match if the only character of the type after that is the first character in the string. So the resulting regexp is:

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,15}$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qY6jY3/1)